# Importing news site via xml/rss from Webforms to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss, webforms

I'm working on a project to rebuild news.byu.edu in Wordpress, and trying to figure out how best to import the articles from the current build (in ASP.net) into a .dev site I'm building with ServerPress's DesktopServer.

Unfortunately, the RSS feed on the site only contains summaries of the articles, so doing an RSS import of that is not particularly useful. I do have access to the back end of the news site. Best I can see it, my options are:

1. Find a WordPress plugin that will handle custom import of individual articles (not the RSS feed) on a large scale. This would be ideal, but I have yet to find one that suits my needs.
2. Rewrite the RSS feed generator on the news site to include all other pertinent information, and not just summaries, then import that. Problem here is that there are a lot of articles, and I'm not sure if making the generator display all of them is a good idea.
3. Write a script to parse the current site's archives and aggregate them into a single .xml that I then import. This seems like it may be a waste  of time, as 2 may well be shorter to implement.

Essentially, my question is, what would be the least time-consuming solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best solution to this will be to use WordPress's HTML Import plugin. This allows for importing selected HTML content from files of various extensions.

Use the recommended [SiteSucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/home.html) app found in the user guide for HTML Import to download the archives of the site. Then set up the configuration of HTML Import to select whatever desired part you want from each page. This technique will work for importing *any* content from *any* site to make posts.